# Install4j hide popup on updatecheck

Tags: auto-update, install4j

In my Install4j Project i use Update Downloader with silent version check. This works fine. Launch schedule is set to "Always". Thats ok cuz i want to check at Start.
When I start my program a small popup window appears for the updatecheck. if an update is available, the update will continue. 
If no update is available, the window closes again. In this case, that is very fast but you can see a popup.

Is it possible to hide this popup?

Comment: What is the value of "Default execution mode" property of the update downloader?

Comment: the value is "unattended mode with progress dialog"

Answer (score 0):

If the "Unattended mode with progress dialog" is used for an installer application, the progress dialog is shown the first time a message or a percentage value is set on the progress bar.

The standard template "Update downloader with silent version check" has the "Check for update" action as its first action in the "Startup" node. If no new version is available, the action fails and the update downloader quits because the "Failure strategy" property of the action is set to "Quit on failure".

The "Check for update" action does not set a message on the progress bar, so the progress dialog is not created in this scenario I just checked that myself with install4j 7.0.4. If you see a progress dialog flashing, you may have added other actions before the "Check for update" action that use the progress bar.

Comment: yes I use a custom action for the update check. But there I do not use the progressbar.
I even deactivated the action but the update window still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (with Install4J Version 8) and disabling all the steps did not solve the issue.

To get it working it is important to actually quit the update installer with an error, then no dialog pop ups.

So to stop the auto update in certain scenarios without the popup, I had to create an "Set a variable action" that would always fail.

[image: Action in Update Installer]

with the following content
[image: Config of the action]

Do not forget to set the conditional expression. That should decide if the application should check for an update